# A functional equation, and what to do when branches appear.

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, functional-equations

How would I analytically solve functional equations like this?

$$f(g(x)) = h(x), x\in \mathcal S$$

if $g$ and $h$ are known, $f$ is what we solve for.

---

I have tried solving special cases, for example $$\cases{g(x) = x^2\\h(x)=(x+0.2)^2}$$

For this one I get multiple solutions when going from $x^2 \to \pm x$ ("undoing" $g$). This could be avoided by splitting the set $\mathcal S$ into two: $\{[-\infty,0],[0,\infty]\}$. But is there some mathematical method / algorithm that can account for the whole set of solutions simultaneously?

Being an engineer I have built something of a "machinery" that can solve it for me, I am just curious of how it may or may not relate to the typical analytical methods.

Comment: If $g$ is invertible then set $x = g^{-1}(y)$ and you will get $f(y) = h(g^{-1}(y))$.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if it is not?

Comment: It might be piecewisely invertible, just like in your example with $g(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Yes. But what if we want to avoid having to keep track of all the pieces and want the solution to do that for us?